How did Padmé know where to go on Mustafar?
In the Star Wars: Revenge of the Sith movie, Padmé went to Mustafar to confront Anakin after learning bad things about him. But, how did she reach him? Earlier, Anakin had only told her he was going to Mustafar. Mustafar was a big planet. How did she know where to land?
Some guesses:

She followed Anakin’s ship’s beacon or something.
There was only one settlement on Mustafar.
She scanned the planet for a human.


Obi-Wan was on the ship with Padmé, so my immediate instinct is that he sensed Anakin through the Force (like Leia sensing Luke in Cloud City in The Empire Strikes Back) and told Padmé where to go, but I'm reluctant to post that as an answer as I don't have any definite proof.

@F1Krazy Padmé didn’t even know that Obi-Wan was in the ship.

@Dr.Doom Did she not?

@F1Krazy - Famously she didn't

@Dr. Doom  "Mustafar was a big planet. How did she know where to land?"  So how would she know where to land if Mustafar was a small but habitable planet?

How did she find the facility?
According to the Star Wars: Revenge of the Sith Movie Scrapbook, there's only one technological settlement on Mustafar that would be observable from space, which answers the question of how she was able to find the approximate location on the planet.

The hazy, bloodred planet Mustafar is covered by active volcanoes.
Despite the hostile surface conditions, a fragile settlement has been
punched into the side of an obsidian mountain, transforming the area
into an enormous energymining facility. It is here that the Separatist
leaders—following the instructions of Darth Sidious—seek refuge from
the Republic army.

How did know precisely where to land?
The Star Wars: Complete Locations factbook advises that landing on Mustafar is extremely difficult, which is one of the reasons why the hideout was sited there in the first place. Padmé would have needed to have been intentionally guided in by the flight traffic-control at the mining facility in order to land on the 'visitor pad', which also neatly explains why her ship ended up right next to Anakin's flyer.

The volcanic breath of Mustafar’s volcanoes and the influence of
Jestefad’s massive magnetic field create a turbulent atmosphere filled
with ash, cyclonic-force updrafts and thermal currents, and titanic
lightning storms. Electromagnetic interference renders scanners
useless and interferes with navigation equipment and control systems.
Landing on Mustafar is therefore an extremely hazardous operation without the aid of the specially shielded landing support equipment at
the mining complex. This includes guidance and tractor beams designed
to safely lead authorized ships to and from orbit.
[a] Landing control room oversees landings on the "visitors" pad.

Why didn't Padmé get refused landing clearance or shot down?
Vader states that he saw Padmé's ship on approach on the monitors. We know from the official novelisation that Anakin had used a backdoor 'deactivation code' to turn off the facility's 'mechanised defences' when he himself landed. Either the defences were still down, or Anakin, having recognised that this wasn't an enemy ship, was able to use the same code to allow his wife to land safely.

[Anakin's] starfighter followed a pre-programmed course toward the planet’s lone installation, an automated lava mine built originally by the Techno Union to draw precious metals from the continuous rivers of burning stone. Upgraded with the finest mechanized defenses that money could buy, the settlement had become the final redoubt of the leaders of the Confederacy of Independent Systems. It was absolutely impenetrable.
Unless one had its deactivation codes.
Which was how the starfighter could land without causing the installation’s defenses to so much as stir.
Revenge of the Sith: Official Novelisation

